# Компиляция Intel C++ compiler приложения x64 на Windows x32

Tags: windows, intel, c++, компилятор

Добрый вечер!
Воспользовалась Intel C++ Compiler отсюда (http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4536674) для компиляции программы. Затем запустила исполняемый файл, на что система выдала предупреждение о том, что приложение не совместимо с текущей версией Windows. Система 32-разрядная.
Как быть, если компиляцию нужно провести именно с помощью этого компилятора? Не переустанавливать же ради этого систему...

Comment: Какая система? На указанной Вами странице заявлено, что д.б. Vista, Win7 или Win8, но не WinXP

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно на x86 собирать ПО для x64 именно этим компилятором, то да, вам надо установить ОС x64(ваш процессор ещё должен её поддерживать).

Попробуйте на VirtualBox поднять ОС x64.

Comment: А это возможно?

Я имею в виду `64-bit Guest OS` под `VirtualBox` на `32-bit Host OS`.

По крайней мере у меня на `DualCore` и `WinXP SP3` не получилось.

Comment: Сам не пробовал, ибо x64 ставлю по умолчанию. Мб эмулятор умеет эмулировать x64.

Comment: Если хостовая ОС 32 битная, то гостевая тоже может быть только 32 битной